# Is asking for materials for an experiment on light and seed germination on-topic?

Tags: support

I want to make an experiment regarding seed germination on some flowering plants, probably Portulaca grandiflora, but not necessary this exact species. Some plants need light to germinate their seeds and I want to determine just how much is needed.

My idea is to use a few batches of seeds, each batch under light of different intensity. The problem is that I don't know what materials should I use to filter/block light. I was thinking of glass plates/dishes/bowls with different degree of transparency, but I don't know if the colour of the glass will influence the wavelenght that reaches the seeds. I could also try some textile cages, but this will require a lot of work I guess.

For this purpose I need some suggestions for materials to use instead of glass. Where should I ask this question, here on G&L, or on Biology, Physics, Lifehacks, Arts&Crafts? Or some other places?

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not sure how to answer your question, although I suspect Arts and Crafts would be out. Lifehacks is probably out too, according to their [Lifehacks Manifesto](http://meta.lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/2431/a-lifehacks-manifesto). @J.Musser is a moderator there, so he might weigh in here.  If a scientific site is best, I'm inclined to agree with Giacomo Catenazzi about Biology. Sorry I couldn't be more help.

Comment: Don't forget that once you have something growing, we'd love to answer further questions here. It would even be great when you ask them to mention what method you used and what worked best. There are some experts here (including you!) about things like lighting, and other people like me, who would love to learn from your experience.

Comment: Hi Alina. I'm just curious, have you asked your question anywhere? If so, I'd love to have a look at it so I can see if you got the help you were looking for.

Comment: Thank you for asking, Sue! I haven't asked it yet. In a few weeks I will take the time to add details to this experiment in order to ask a single question. I need to take some exams first and meanwhile I can't think of anything else.

Comment: Thanks Alina. I hope you enjoy your exams!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it should be asked in Biology SE.

The topic of the question is about having reproducible conditions, and not about plants.